# jquery .val() prints value of textarea with lag of 1 character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
this.$textarea // upon expansion in browser console
value: "xx" // shows value as 'xx'
length: 1

this.$textarea.val() // console.log(this.$textarea.val())
x // printes values with lag of 1. ie. a -> '', ab -> 'a', abc -> 'ab'
```

jquery .val() prints value of textarea with lag of 1 charactor.

Comment: on which event you are doing it? on keydown?

Comment: Which event you are doing it, keypress?

Comment: onkeypress the value of the input element will not be updated, you need to wait for keyup http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnP62/1/

Comment: change it to keyup and see

Comment: keypress calls a function, in that function i'm performing 'this.$textarea.val()'

Comment: keypress is triggered when your key is pressed you need to wait till keyup.. What @ArunPJohny said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on keypress the value of the input element will not be updated, you need to wait for keyup

```
$('input').on('keydown keypress keyup', function (e) {
    console.log(e.type, this.value)
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hnP62/1)

courtsey:- [Arun Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny)